# Posts without featured image using other post's featured image

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop

I am using the following code (see bottom) to display a custom post called 'artists'. I am also using `<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )` so I can set the background of a div using the post thumbnail (I don't think this is the problem).

I want to display all of the posts on one page so use `'numberposts' => -1,`. I have noticed that the posts after the first twelve posts are using another posts featured image if they do not have one assigned.

If I assign a featured image to any post in question then it does show the correct image. I just don't understand why every post after the first twelve are using another posts featured image. Is there something wrong with the loop as I'm using `'numberposts' => -1,`? There's no harm in this as I'll be assigning an image to each one but want to understand why this might be happening.

[image]

```
   <?php

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' 
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

    <li class="artist-list artist-mobile">
        <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>">

                <div class="artist-box mobile" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
                <div class="mobile-link"></div>
                <div class="info-back">
                <div class="info-post"><p>VIEW ARTIST</p></div>
                <div class="cross">+</div>
                </div>
                            </div>
                <div class="artist-name"><?php the_title();?></div>
        </a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: `<?php endforeach; ?>` is not missing in your code, is it?

Comment: Can we see the full loop code in context? Also, *which specific post's featured image* is being used out of place? Is it a specific post ID?

Comment: `numberposts`? what's that? I think that should be: `posts_per_page`.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam `get_posts()` takes `numberposts` as a valid parameter, interchangeably with `posts_per_page`, and converts `numberposts` to `posts_per_page` before passing the args array to `WP_Query()`.

Comment: I've added the full loop and a screenshot as you can see they are using a few different post's featured image. Not a specific post ID.

Comment: Are the permalink and title correct on the impacted posts, or do they output the permalink/title of the same post as the incorrect featured image?

Comment: They are correct!

Answer (score 0):

> If I assign a featured image to any post in question then it does show
>   the correct image. I just don't understand why every post after the
>   first twelve are using another posts featured image.

I think the problem is that you do not reset `$image` if the current post doesn't have a featured thumbnail.

You should add for example:

```
<?php 
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
else:
    $image = array( 'http://example.com/default.jpg' );
endif; 
?>
```

since you are using `$image[0]` in your code.